# Setting up Backstage plugins

Tags: plugins, backstage, pagerduty

When setting up Backstage plugins, is it reasonable to integrate a custom plugin when a community plugin already exists?

I tried integrating the community plugin available for PagerDuty, but Roadie has a custom plugin that includes the capabilities I needed.